# Complete guide to cross-language grammar

Tags: grammar

Wondering what the best (free) resources are for learning about grammar *generically* across languages. I have seen a lot of "Guide to the X grammar", but not "Guide to grammar in general". Would like to find a resource that describes grammar cross-linguistically.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "grammar" here?

Comment: We don't do shopping requests here. Your best option would be to try a few textbooks and then see which frameworks fit your thinking.

Comment: I'd suggest rephrasing this so it's not so broad, otherwise it's liable to get closed. "Grammar" is a broad field that encompasses the majority of linguistics. Are you looking for textbooks or online courses or something of that sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your question can be paraphrased along these lines. "I would like to study the structure of a lot of languages, and I would like to know what kinds of things languages 'do'". In other words, I think you're looking for a comprehensive compendium of grammatical features across languages. There is no single compendium like that: such a work would be monstrously huge and take forever to write. Payne's *Describing morphosyntax* is, however, a fairly good book that presents some of the range of variation found in at least certain kinds of constructions. This will introduce you to some of the range of certain grammatical constructions. There are a number of other good works of that type, including ones that focus on coherent grammatical subdomains such as "agreement". I will also mention [WALS](https://wals.info/) as a standard reference for looking things up, e.g. if you want to know about word order or definite articles.

On the other hand, if you want to know how the (integrated, full) grammars of languages work, the best approach might be to investigate the full details of the grammar of a half-dozen specific typologically-distinct languages. For example, Ancient Greek, Swahili, Chinese, Tamil, Inuit (this is an illustrative suggestion: you could probably substitute Sanskrit for Greek. The goal was to pick 6 unrelated, typologically-divergent languages and swapping Chinese for Japanese thwarts the latter desideratum). Obviously, the more languages you investigate, the better. The difference in method that I'm pointing to is that the "many languages very narrowly" approach teaches you more about how languages differ in one specific area, and the "learn 6 languages approach" emphasizes the necessity of understanding all of the parts of a single language, so that you know "the grammar" of some language (not "a bit about the grammar").

There is a third possible answer in case you mean "I would like to investigate the structure of languages by grammatical elicitation with native speakers of languages: how do I proceed". I hate to say, there is no good textbook for that.

Comment: Thank you [this](https://books.google.com/books/about/Describing_Morphosyntax.html?id=LC3DfjWfCiwC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button#v=onepage&q&f=false) was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Wondering if Sanskrit, Hindi, Tibetan, or Japanese add much variation to the list of languages you already provided.